# Logical indexing of chars in heterogenous cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, logical-operators

I have a heterogenous cell array containing mostly numbers but one column of characters. I would like to identify those rows in which the value in the column of characters is equal to a certain string, `'X'`. My array looks something like this:

```
array_name = { [0] [2] 'X' ; 
               [4] [1] 'X' ; 
               [9] [7] 'A' ; 
               [9] [1] 'X' ; 
               [4] [4] 'B'};
```

My question is two-fold:

(1) Since using `array_name == 'X'` does not return the logical vector I would expect when using it on a numerical array, how do I do this?

(2) How can I create a new array consisting only of those rows which meet the condition that the value in the character column be equal to `'X'`, so that my output would look like this:

```
new_array = { [0] [2] 'X' ; 
              [4] [1] 'X' ; 
              [9] [1] 'X'};
```

I am only interested in (1) in so far as I assume it will be necessary for (2).

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the third column as a comma separated list and concatenate it to an array, then you can use logical indexing:

```
L=[array_name{:,3}]=='X'
new_array=array_name(L,:)
```

Alternatively you can use `strcmpi` which can deal with more than one char.

```
L=strcmpi(array_name(:,3),'X')
new_array=array_name(L,:)
```

Comment: Oh nice answer haha I definitely over-complicated things. +1

Comment: And so did I. Thank you so much. Could you perhaps briefly explain in a comment why this works when using brackets around array_name and it doesn't when you simply use "array_name{:,3} == 'X'"?

Comment: The `array_name{:,3}` is a comma separated list, comparing using `eq` is not possible. You have to use `[]` to get an array. You can find an explanation about comma separated lists here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b

Comment: I see now that my answer is similar to yours, but I cover the case of non-uniform contents (numbers and strings) in the same column, so I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your 1st question sorry, but here is an answer for the 2nd one which I think will answer the 1st one as well.

The answer uses [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html?refresh=true) and the advantage they provide in that one can look into cell arrays at once and get logical values when matches occur.

Example:

```
clear
clc

array_name = { [0] [2] 'X';
    [4] [1] 'X';
    [9] [7] 'A' ;
    [9] [1] 'X'  ;
    [4] [4] 'B'}

%// Check for string 'X' in the cell array.
FindX = regexp('X',array_name(:,end))
```

The output is a cell containing logical indices for matches:

```
FindX = 

    [1]
    [1]
    []
    [1]
    []
```

Then check for non-empty cells, i.e. those having a value of 1; a match

```
Idx = ~cellfun(@isempty,FindX);

Idx =

     1
     1
     0
     1
     0
```

You can then use logical indexing into the original cell array:

```
OutRows = array_name(Idx,:)

OutRows = 

    [0]    [2]    'X'
    [4]    [1]    'X'
    [9]    [1]    'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that [`strcmp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) works on cell arrays, and returns a `0` if one of its arguments is not a string (as well as if the strings are different). So,

- For question (1):

  ```
  result1 = strcmp(array_name,'X');
  ```

  which gives, in your example,

  ```
  result1 =
       0     0     1
       0     0     0
       0     0     0
       0     0     1
       0     0     0
  ```
- For question (2):

  ```
  result2 = array_name(strcmp(array_name(:,3),'X'),:);
  ```

  which gives

  ```
  result2 = 
      [0]    [2]    'X'
      [4]    [1]    'X'
      [9]    [1]    'X'
  ```

The advantage of this approach is that it works even if column 3 does not contain only strings. For example,

```
array_name = { [0] [2] 'X' ; 
               [4] [1]  5 ; 
               [9] [7] 'A' ; 
               [9] [1] 'X' ; 
               [4] [4]  6 };

result1 =
     0     0     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     0

result2 = 
    [0]    [2]    'X'
    [9]    [1]    'X'
```